# Bootstrap - Dropdown menu click based on URL query parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the HTML & JS Code used to trigger the bootstrap dropdown menu to trigger clicks based on the query parameter value.

http://localhost:9000/page.html?key=2222

As key = 2222, it has to trigger `<a>` tag with data-key="2222". But, nothing happens. Also, I am not sure how to match the query parameter value with `<a>` tag data key attribute to trigger. Can anyone guide me please?

Thanks

```js
const paramsExist = window.location.href.split('?').length > 1;
const qp = paramsExist ? window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&') : [];

qp.map(q => {
    const k = q.split('=')[0];
    const v = q.split('=')[1];
    this[k] = v;
    $('#startDate').parent().find('.dropdown-menu a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<div class="apply-title">
    <h3>Start Date</h3> 
    <div class="dropdown start-date">
       <button id="startDate" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle">01 Dec 2021</button> 
       <div aria-labelledby="startDate" class="dropdown-menu">
          <a type="button" data-key="1111" class="dropdown-item">01 Dec 2021</a>
          <a type="button" data-key="2222" class="dropdown-item">01 Nov 2021</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this jQuery

```
const paramsExist = window.location.href.split('?').length > 1;
const qp = paramsExist ? window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&') : [];
$('#startDate').siblings(".dropdown-menu").find("[data-"+qp[0]+"]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: data-key is missing. have to match with data-key value

Comment: Yes qp[0] = "key=222", so I am merging [data-key=222]